# How to update taxonomy term of a node using services

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 6, services

I have created a new node using Services 3 module successfully, the code is below

```
{

 "type":"page",
"title":"New test page",
"taxonomy": { 
       "tid" :"367928"
      }

}
```

Configuration:

Drupal version = 6.26,

url = serviceurl/node,

App = Postman application in chrome,

Method = POST,

data = json.

But when i tried to edit the taxonomy term of the node using same format as below , its not working

url = serviceurl/node/node-id,

Method = PUT,

data = json.

```
{

"type":"page",
"title":"New updated title of the Page",
"taxonomy": { 
       "tid" :"367930"
      }
}
```

When I checked the node, the title is getting updated where as the taxonomy term remains the same.
I searched a lot on the net, but could not find any solution. Can anyone please help to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think your JSON format to create node is wrong. Please check the created node. I guess it creates node but with empty taxonomy field.

The correct format to create a node having taxonomy term is like follows.

Assuming that your 'widget type' for 'term reference field' is 'Select list' or 'Check boxes/radio buttons'

```
{
    "title": "my title",
    "type": "page",
    "field_mynodeterm": {
        "und": "3"
    }
}
```

here `field_mynodeterm` is machine name of your 'Term reference field' (which is used in content type).

Similarly you can use the same format to update the node

```
{
    "title": "my updated title",
    "type": "page",
    "field_mynodeterm": {
        "und": "5"
    }
}
```

If you use 'Autocomplete term widget (tagging)' as widget type for term reference field, the JSON format would be the following

```
{
    "title": "my updated title",
    "type": "page",
    "field_mynodeterm": {
        "und": "termname"
    }
}
```

I tested the above scenarios and working fine. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Krishna, I tried your solution. But the taxonomy is not saving if I use "photo_categories"(my taxonomy) method, because that field doesnot exist in my content type. Because I have a taxonomy called Photo Categories(machine name is 'photo_categories', which has 3 terms in it like "Sports", "Movies", and "News". And I enabled this taxonomy for Page content type. Hence there is no separate name for this taxonomy in my Page content type. Code is used is {
"type":"page",
"title":"Page test  from Webservice1111",
  "page_categories": {
        "und": "367930"
    }
}